# Custom routing via nginx - read from third party source

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka, url-routing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to nginx, and am wondering if it can help me to solve a use-case we've encountered.

I have n nodes,which are reading from from a kafka topic with the same group id, which means that each node has disjoint data, partitioned by some key.

Nginx has no way of knowing apriori which node has data corresponding to which keys. But we can build an API or have a redis instance which can tell us the node given the key.

Is there a way nginx can incorporate third party information of this kind to route requests?

I'd also welcome any  answers, even if it doesn't involve nginx.

Comment: As asked the question is too vague/broad, please refine. `Is there a way nginx can incorporate third party information of this kind to route requests?` I doubt it, unless you use lua (in which case anythings possible) but you could perhaps work towards using [consistent_hash](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/consistent_hash/) if there is any attribute of the requests you can use such that similar requests are served by the same node. If you partition the requests in the same way you partition the nodes - that seems viable.

Comment: oh whoops, and I forgot to mention the general scope here is better suited to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Consistent hashes don't work for me, because I have  no idea how Kafka partitions. Thanks for pointing me to Lua, it seems it can do what I want, but not sure how easy it it to implement, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nginx has no way of knowing apriori which node has data corresponding to which keys

Nginx doesn't need to know. You would need to do this in Kafka Streams RPC layer with [Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html). (Spring-Kafka has an `InteractiveQueryService` interface, btw, that can be used from Spring Web).

If you want to present users with a single address for the KStreams HTTP/RPC endpoints, then that would be a standard [Nginx `upstream` definition](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) for a reverse proxy, which would route to *any* of the backend servers, which in-turn communicate with themselves to fetch the necessary key/value, and return the response back to the client.

> I have no idea how Kafka partitions

You could [look at the source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/BuiltInPartitioner.java#L285) and see it uses a `murmur2` hash, which is [available in Lua](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/lua/murmurhash2/), and can be used in Nginx.

But again, this is a rabbit hole you should probably avoid.

---

Other option, use Kafka Connect to dump data to Redis (or whatever database you want). Then write a very similar HTTP API service, then (optionally) point Nginx at that.